# Importing Visual Foxpro database to SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, import, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am trying to import tables from a Visual Foxpro database into my 2008 SQL Server using *SQL Server Import and Export Wizard*.

My problem is that some of the column's types are failing to be auto-detected. When I open the mapping of the tables with the problem columns the columns type is set to *129*. For all of them the type should be *text*, but my problem is that their are over 200 tables I need to import and I don't have the time to scroll through all the tables and change the column's types.

So my question is, is there a way to automatically default the type to *text* if the wizard can't detect what type it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for the Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx):

> The SQL Server Import and Export Wizard uses the mapping files that
>   Integration Services provides to map data types from one database
>   version or system to another... By default, the mapping files in XML format are installed
>   to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\MappingFiles.
>
> If your business requires different mappings between data types, you can
>   update the mappings to affect the mappings that the wizard performs.

You could use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out which file it is using and update it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual FoxPro available, you could try the Upsizing Wizard available here: http://vfpx.codeplex.com/releases/view/10224